# QooxDoo Contrib confusion

Tags: qooxdoo

We are working towards a PC based software client for our industrial control module box and we are using QooxDoo for the UI.

I wish to use the qxe package for the StatusBar widget it provides. However, there is no clear direction on how to acquire the package. The docs (Qx 2.1.1) refer to a SVN repository (https://qooxdoo-contrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/qooxdoo-contrib/), which seems to be empty as of today.

We would also later like to use the contributed themes in our product.

Any help would be great.

Thanks and best regards,
Vishal Sapre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qooxdoo-contrib SF project was upgraded recently to their Allura platform, during which the SVN repo URL changed. The updated one is:

https://svn.code.sf.net/p/qooxdoo-contrib/code/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib

The old repo has been retired, to avoid confusion (hence it's empty). The new URL is also what you get looking at the [qxe homepage entry](http://qooxdoo.org/contrib/project#qxe) at qooxdoo.org. For contrib-specific information I suggest that you start there.

If you follow this [blog post](http://news.qooxdoo.org/qooxdoo-contrib-is-on-allura), applying the referenced patch to your qooxdoo SDK, the change should be transparent for you project. Ie. the reference to qxe via the `contrib://qxe/<version>/Manifest.json` pseudo URL should continue to work.

Besides the new repo URL nothing has changed in using contributions, so the correpsonding [manual entry](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.1.x/pages/tool/generator/generator_config_articles.html#library-key-and-manifest-files) you are referring to basically applies. For offline usage, though, as the tarball downloading feature is not supported with SF's new repositories anymore, the easiest would be to let the Generator download it once (using the `contrib://` entry in config.json), then locate it on your disk ('generate.py info' will list your local download path) and copy it from there.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. That was valuable info. Meanwhile I also noticed that each contribution lists its own SVN link, and I started to checkout individual contributions. That is working. Do you suggest I should still go ahead and use the link you have given to download the entire trunk of qooxdoo-contrib. I mean, do you think contributions might have cross dependencies ?

Comment: I would only check out specific contributions, not the entire repository. Individual contribs might have dependencies to other contribs, but they should state so in their readme. Then you would need to check out those others too. But these are usually few and shallow dependencies, and there is generally no danger to run into a deep recursion which would make manual checkouts painful.